# Are mods notified when users edited a closed question?

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

Strangely enough, I'm used to vote for reopening others' questions on SO, but since I'm new on this site, I can't really vote to reopen [my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91554/equally-distributing-child-nodes-around-parent-nodes). (Since it's put on hold by a mod I don't think users can vote to reopen anyway?)

The reason for closing it is that the relevant code is not in the question. For some reason I forgot to do that and the question got closed. This is completely fair and I would do the same thing and now I have fixed my question.

The question is, how do they know I fixed it and reopen it? There doesn't seem to be a way for new users to notify mods at all... Or are they automatically added to the Review page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, mods are not notified about this.  When this happens, the question is put into the reopen queue for regular users (and mods).

The only case of a notification for a mod would be if, for instance, a single mod closes a question and a user pings them.

Comment: So how do I get my question reopened? I guess regular users can vote for that since it's put back into the closed queue?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Right.  Just wait for other users (maybe even a mod) to review it.

Comment: @ Jamal Cool, thanks!

Comment: Closed queue? Don't you mean the re-open queue?

Comment: Yep!  I was writing this late at night.  Thanks, @SimonAndréForsberg

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for adding the code.  On further consideration, though, I think that your question is currently more appropriate for Stack Overflow than Code Review, since you are asking to change the behaviour of the code — fixing a bug, so to speak, with the layout algorithm.

There are [existing Stack Overflow questions about graph layout algorithms](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=graph+layout+algorithm).  Some [specific suggestions](//stackoverflow.com/q/5028433/1157100) include using graphviz (for which a [Python module](https://graphviz.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) exists) and using [force-directed graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) (essentially a Physics simulation where the vertices act as particles that repel each other).

I apologize for the inconvenience, but I'm going to close the question again on Code Review.  If, after implementing the suggestions above, you are still not satisfied with the results, you can ask on Stack Overflow.  If you are satisfied with the results but would like better performance or cleaner code, we would love to have you ask again here on Code Review.

Comment: I was thinking whether I should ask on SO or Code Review too, but I chose the latter because I thought my question was more about optimizing the output of program than fixing a specific bug. If this question is asked on SO there's a chance that it will be closed as "too board". Anyway, thanks for giving me possible solutions to my question. I have thought of assigning each vertex forces, but it might be overkill for such simply program.